# A basic question about python class definitions

Tags: python, programming-languages

What is the difference between saying:

```
class foo:
    pass
```

and

```
class foo(object):
    pass
```

?

Comment: should be a lowercase 'o' in object

Comment: So, what is a 'calss' anyway? :P Maybe edit your title :)

Answer (score 4):

The latter declares a [new-style class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).

Comment: What a great community. Thanks everybody and pardon about asking duplicate question ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that it is only different in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, both class definitions create "new-style" classes (the only type of class available).

Comment: @reza: If the answer is what you were looking for, please accept it using the tick on the left.

Answer (score 3):

"Classes and instances come in two flavors: old-style (or classic) and new-style."
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Answer (score 2):

Old-style classes don't extend the built-in 'object' type. New-style classes do. If you're writing new code, use new-style classes. If you're working with old code that is already using old-style classes, well... I say go with it just to insure that all classes act the same way.

Here's a good rundown of the differences: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html
And here's a collection of links for more: http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

I'll note that new-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2, so if you're seeing code that uses old-style classes, and you're going to use it with, say, Python 2.7, you might want to run a quick test to make sure it's not so aged that it doesn't work in newer versions of Python.

Comment: Most cases of old-style classes is just people too lazy to put that "object" in the class definition. It's not really an indication of code age.

Comment: Some of us aren't lazy, just forgetful, or in a hurry.